# Numbering format for listings (lstlisting)

Tags: listings

I'm writing a document with a lot of listings ini it. I need to index the listing with the following format:
"**Listing a.b**" with:
**a** the chapter (arabic) and
**b** the order of occurence in that chapter (arabic).

I have tried

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}}
```

But this creates **a** the chapter (arabic) and **b** the section of that chapter (arabic).

I have done similar thing for tables succesfully (in cls file), using:

```
\AtBeginDocument{ \renewcommand \thetable{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \@arabic\c@chapter.\fi \@arabic\c@table} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Apparently it's as simple as:

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand\thelstlisting{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}%
}
```